# Compiler and datatypes => c as reference

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I have accumulated three different questions but of similar context in this post. The following are the same.

1. Sequence of steps from source->executable
2. 32/64 bit versions of compiler
3. Dependence of c datatypes' size on compiler

#### Q1: Sequence of steps from source->executable

I presume the following are the steps through which an executable is produced from a source file

- The source file written is written in any of the high/middle level language is preprocessed by the compiler.
- When we use **GCC/G++** then **gcc -save-temps -c** while generate a **.S and a .O** file which are the assembly (readable) and the object code (not human readable) respectively.
- The final stage is this object code is linked to resolve the unknown symbols to create a machine (or) executable code.

So the question here is are these assumptions right?.Often I see the terms object and machine codes used interchangeably. What is the exact difference between the two.?

#### Q2: 32/64 bit versions of compiler

Where in exactly in the above steps of Q1 does the compiler type impacts. Is it that the generated assembly code that gets changed?

#### Q3: Dependence of c datatypes' size on compiler

As of c-programming is concerned, Is the size of the data-type dependent on the compiler type (or) hardware type. Please elaborate on the dependence of these factors. Though I see some discussions with Q3 in stack overflow, I am still puzzled about this.

Answer (score 2):

**Q1**

That's about right, but there may be no assembly stage. And "preprocessed" is a nice little word that's overloaded with meaning.

Object and machine code are often almost the same. Object code may contain machine code or some interpretable code, not-yet-machine code. Object code often isn't the final code for execution and needs further processing by a linker. Executables, which contain machine code, often need some processing similar to that of by a linker, but this part is done by the OS. It's desirable to have executables relocatable, that is, to be able to load them at any location in the memory to run them there. Relocation involves fixing up addresses inside of the executable after it's loaded but before it's executed. Linking to DLLs at run time is another linker-like function performed by the OS.

**Q2**

"Preprocessing" is the first step where types and their sizes start to appear. Compilers have to perform type checking, type conversion and code/data generation. At all those steps types cannot be ignored. Is 0xFFFF an `int` or an `unsigned int`? How much memory should the compiler reserve for a pointer? How much space should be allocated for an array of 100 `doubles`? How exactly does the compiler promote `chars` to `ints`? What about code optimization? Answers to all those questions require knowing type sizes. Definitely, the resulting assembly or machine code will depend on them.

**Q3**

In theory, type sizes depend on the compiler. In practice, to avoid the unnecessary overhead of simulation of the types not supported directly by the target hardware, the types that you have correspond directly to those that are supported by the hardware. C is pretty much a portable assembler in its origin and nature and that should explain a lot of its "oddities" (being too primitive, letting you shoot yourself in a foot easily, having a number of undefined and implementation-specific behaviors, etc etc).

Comment: How is "preprocessed" overloaded in meaning? The C Standard stricly defines what the preprocessor does and when it is done. Obviously the "preprocessed source" is the preprocessor's output... (`gcc -E` or `cpp`)

Comment: @rubenvb The OP effectively hid all the compilation behind the word "preprocessed". This is how I understood his words. Hence the word is overloaded with meaning.